# Custom bar button item not sizing properly

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I have a custom app that includes a custom bar button item, with Swift 3 it was sized appropriately but after updating to Swift 4 it is no longer sizing to the constraints provided. This is my code:

```
let infoButton = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
infoButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "info button white.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
infoButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(StartViewController.infoButtonPressed), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
infoButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 25)

let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: infoButton)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
```

I tried changing the CGRect numbers to see if there would be any change, and there is not, it is sizing to the limits of the navigation bar, and frankly now looks quite ugly.

[image]
Any ideas about what changed in Swift 4? I am running Xcode 9.0(9A235)

Comment: The issue may be with iOS 11. I ran the app on another phone running iOS 10.3.2(14F89) and the info button is appropriately sized, running it on my first device with iOS 11.0.1(15A402) I get the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting constraints like this:

```
infoButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
infoButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
```

Or use images of the correct size.

Comment: Hi @user1698875, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.